# SQL Percentage Count Query By Date

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I am able to calculate the percentage count on a particular date in a Microsoft Access 2007 SQL query using:

```
SELECT Date, Val, (Count(Val) / (SELECT Count(*) From Table HAVING Date=#7/31/2012#) as PercentVal    
FROM Table  
GROUP BY Date, Val  
HAVING Date=#7/31/2012#
```

However, I would like to make this same calculation over every date using the count totals . For instance, the query:

```
SELECT Date, Val, Count(*) AS CountVal  
FROM Table  
GROUP BY Date, Val
```

finds the counts in every period. I would like to add an additional column with the percent counts. However, I can't seem to figure out how to calculate count percentage in every period without using the above block of text and setting up queries for each individual period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subquery it like this:

```
SELECT A.ADate, A.Val, COUNT(A.Val) / B.DateCount
FROM Table1 AS A
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT C.ADate, COUNT(*) AS DateCount
    FROM Table1 C
    GROUP BY C.ADate
) AS B ON A.ADate = B.ADate
GROUP BY A.ADate, A.Val, B.DateCount
```

Comment: Taking a subquery approach seems to be the correct approach. I had to change the COUNT(*) in the second select statement to Count(C.Val) in order to impose a condition on Val that I had left out for simplicity.